# Config Eclipse to open files in external editor

Tags: notepad++, eclipse

We can go in Windows > Preferences, Editors > File Assossiation to config external editor for any file type.

I've done that and now I can right click on any file and go Open With to open that file in external editor. Eclipse is even able to identify when file was changed.

But I'd like Eclipse to automatically open the external editor, just when I double click the file. Is there a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is correct. Maybe when you added your editor you forgot to set it as default editor.